# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' even with adding int to the front of score

Tags: python

```
score = int(0)
name = str(input("What is your name?"))
print("Hello " + name + "!")
pi = input( name + ", can you tell me the value of pi? ")

if score >= '6' :
    print ("congratulations, " +name + " you passed the exam! You'll be richer than your wildest dreams!" )
else:
    print: ("Listen, " +name + " you screwed up big time, with grades like this you'll be stuck working in a Best Buy for the rest of your life")
```

The problem is the if score statement, that's where I get the error. I need to have this "quiz" graded. I've been working on this all night, I'm not a good coder. Please help me

thank you in advance

Comment: You are assigning score = 0 in the first line. So, you want to use value of pi for condition check or score because it will always give output of else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int` in `score = int(0)` isn't neccessary. You can just write `score = 0`. For the comparison, do you really want to use the number 6 as a string? If not then just do this `score >= 6` and it should work. I didn't test it but the code below should work.

```
score = 0
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello " + name + "!")
pi = input(name + ", can you tell me the value of pi?")

if score >= 6:
    print("congratulations, " + name + " you passed the exam! You'll be richer than your wildest dreams!")
else:
    print("Listen, " + name + " you screwed up big time, with grades like this you'll be stuck working in a Best Buy for the rest of your life")
```

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't print the lines after the last question

Comment: That's because score is not bigger or equal to 6.

Comment: I edited the code, try now. You had `print: ()` on the last line, which is the wrong python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `int` (score) with `string` ('6'). Try:

```
if score > 6: # <--omit the quotes
   etc...
```

Comment: I did that but then it doesn't give the grade or print it

Comment: @GeorgeMarket of course - `score` is not incremented anywhere in your code so it's never greater than 6. What did you expect ?